# exactness on pullback of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $i:Y⊂X$ is a closed subvariety of a variety X.

Suppose there is an exact sequence of coherent sheaves on X:
$$
0→A→B→i∗C→0
$$
Suppose C is locally free on Y. Pulling the above exact sequence on Y, does it still remain left exact. I want to check whether $Tor^1(i^{-1}i_*C,O_Y)$ is zero or not.

```
I saw that to check $Tor^1=0$, it suffices to check at stalks.
```

In this case, if p is a point on X−Y, then $i∗(O_Y)=0$, hence $Tor1=0$.
 If $p\in Y$ then since C is assumed to be locally free, it is free at the stalk at p, and stalk of $i^{-1}i_*C$ is same as that of stalk at $C$, hence $Tor^1$ is again zero. Is this correct.

Comment: OK, up to a point, but there is no reason to conclude that $Tor_1=0$
at $p\in Y$ from what you said previously. Consider  $X=Spec k[x]$,
$Y$ the closed point defined by $(x)$ and $A,B,C$ the sheaves corresponding to $xk[x]$, $k[x]$ and $k$, then your assumptions hold but $Tor_1(k,k)\not=0$.

Comment: thanks. But is it not true that $Tor^1(M,N)=0$, if $M$ of $N$ is free.
How can the above situation be rectified.

Comment: The point is that it matters what ring you are using. If you are computing Tor over X or over Y you get different answers. Your $M$ or $N$ would have to be flat over the ring ($\mathscr O_X$) you are taking the Tor over, not over something else ($\mathscr O_Y$).

Comment: thanks..so in above question, there is a $Tor^1$ mapping to $i^*A$ on $Y$.

Is it correct that $Tor^1$ is zero at the generic point of $Y$, hence it is supported on a closed subset of $Y$.

Comment: more precisely, $i^*A \rightarrow i^*B$ is generically injective, if $rank(A)$ is positive.